# HSQLDB delete trigger is causing problem in subquery

Tags: sql, triggers, subquery, hsqldb

I am having a problem in HSQLDB delete trigger, somehow it's not working as expected.

I am trying to implement logs of every change in database.

For sample testing, I execute these SQL statements:

```
CREATE TABLE msg (
  id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(80)
);

CREATE TABLE log (
    id INTEGER IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    row_id INTEGER,
    op VARCHAR(30),
    status VARCHAR(30)
);

insert into msg (id, name) values (0, 'First Test Message');
insert into log (id, row_id, op, status) values (0, 0, 'insert', 'pending');

update log set status = 'done' where id = 0;
```

Now, I create a delete trigger and delete rows from the `msg` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_log_delete_msg
AFTER DELETE ON msg REFERENCING OLD ROW AS old_row FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC
    INSERT INTO log(row_id, op, status)
    SELECT old_row.id, 'delete', CASE status WHEN 'pending' THEN 'cancel' ELSE 'pending' END FROM log
    WHERE row_id = old_row.id AND NOT status = 'cancel' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

    UPDATE log SET status = 'cancel'
    WHERE row_id = old_row.id AND op = 'insert' AND status = 'pending';
END

delete from msg where id = 0;
```

Until now, it's working as expected:

```
insert into msg values (0, 'Test Message Again');
insert into log (row_id, op, status) values (0, 'insert', 'pending');
```

This, time deleting will cause a problem:

```
delete from msg where id = 0;
```

Expected behavior of status in log should be `cancel` not `pending`, why it is causing the problem?

Comment: You can debug this by checking the ROW_COUNT returned by your INSERT and UPDATE statements inside the trigger http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#dac_diagnostics_state

Comment: @fredt I think, row are updated / inserted well, only for delete it's making fault for last delete operation if before Insert state is done only.

Comment: I mean the INSERT and UPDATE inside the CREATE TRIGGER.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work if you do not reuse the ID value zero. When you reuse the value, the old rows in the `log` table cause unexpected results.

```
insert into msg values (1, 'Test Message Again');
insert into log (row_id, op, status) values (1, 'insert', 'pending');
delete from msg where id = 1;                                        

-- dump of the log table

0,0,insert,done
1,0,delete,pending
2,1,insert,cancel
3,1,delete,cancel
```

Comment: the exacted result for log table should something like this
```
0,1,insert,done
1,1,delete,pending
2,1,insert,cancel
3,1,delete,cancel
```
the trick is that, after `Insert` no need of `Delete` operation for same id if Inserting operation is pending for another table, However if it's Done in another table then Delete operation should be pending...

Comment: If you are logging multiple tables in the 'log' table you need to include the name of the table in addition to the row id in the log file. You also need to avoid reusing row ids in the same table.  If you do not do these things, you get mixed-up results with your existing SQL trigger code.

Comment: Mostly I do not reuse Same Id, but some time have to, I still can't think, why my logic is causing issue when status is done, however other wise it's working well. see screen-shot

Comment: My final solutions, if without done status: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYaoF.png, But same logic when status is done, looks last problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjtJw.png